# How do I enable protobuf-net.BuildTools OneOf support via project file?

Tags: protobuf-net

The [documentation](http://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/contract_first.html) seems to indicate this should be possible but I'm not having any luck getting this working as described.

net5.0 project, protobuf-net (3.0.101) and protobuf-net.BuildTools(3.0.101) are the only NuGet references

simple .proto file defined as:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message ExampleMessage {
    oneof SomeGroup {
        int32 foo = 1;
        string bar = 3;
        double baz = 4;
    }
}
```

.csproj file snippet:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalFiles Include="example.proto" OneOf="enum"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Code generates, but does *not* include any enum definition.

I know this is similar to another recent question, but that one doesn't address attributes and I wasn't permitted to comment there.

Comment: Interesting question; I'll need to remind myself, quite honestly - the config API for analyzers/generators is not intuitive

Comment: Thanks for taking a look (and for the library!)  
I'm using oneof in a container/packet style message that has dozens of possible members so the enum feature is killer for discriminating the 'actual' message type programmatically. The protoc-generated stuff would be fine but I'm already using protobuf-net for some internal serialization and I don't want to have to reference both

Comment: I'll see if I can find what is up tomorrow; not at a desk now

Comment: 3.0.115 should be en-route to NuGet now: https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net.BuildTools/3.0.115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: there was an error in the tool bundling; I have fixed this, and with an imminent build (currently working through the CI build), this should be resolved; the config in the question now works, with the additional output in the C#:

```cs
public SomeGroupOneofCase SomeGroupCase => (SomeGroupOneofCase)__pbn__SomeGroup.Discriminator;

public enum SomeGroupOneofCase
{
    None = 0,
    Foo = 1,
    Bar = 3,
    Baz = 4,
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior after updating the `UsageDemo` project to the latest version (currently 3.0.129). I'm not so much interested in `OneOf` as I am `ListSet`, however neither option added to the `AdditionalFiles` node has any effect. Any idea?